# How to detect HTTP request by analysing JavaScript & HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, security, html-sanitizing

I'm wondering if we can do some analysis on JavaScript code to detect whether a web page contains these JS would send HTTP request to other domain.

For example, some one put their static web page files in my web server(DOMAIN A), and I don’t want their file to send HTTP request to other site(DOMAIN B, for example).

There’re some ways they can do this:

1. Using img tag: `<img src=“http://domain.b.com/statics”>`
2. Using script tag.
3. Using form tag.
4. Using iframe tag.

What’s more, we can also use JS to generate HTTP request, for example:

```
var f = document.createElement('form');
f.action = "http://domain.b.com/statics";
...
```

Javascript could be obfuscated, the javascript above could be compressed as:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c]=k[c]||c}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('4 0=3.2(\'1\');0.5="9://8.7.6/10";',10,11,'f|form|createElement|document|var|action|com|b|domain|http|statics'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Comment: Have a look at phantomjs.

Comment: Do you want to analyze this by programming or manually? If manually, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) would be the best to inspect HTTP transactions.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be tricky to prevent this entirely - there will always be new tricks that malicious 3rd-party content could employ (that you haven't thought of or that didn't exist at time of writing).

Testing the content in a sandbox (e.g. PhantomJS) and then seeing if it makes any such requests is a possibility, but if the malicious code was aware you were doing that they might try and work around it.

You could consider taking the approach used in Wikis/forums where HTML markup isn't allowed but a custom markup (offering a very limited subset of HTML functionality) is used to generate HTML for the client.

Comment: The overriding security principal is that it's safer to explicitly white-list what should be allowed, rather than black-listing what is disallowed.